# EF Core Migration Failing

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am new to Code First building with EF Core and need a little assistance.  I have a solution with 3 projects: DataProvider, DataModel, UserInterface.  I am roughly following the example in Jon P Smith's book Entity Framework Core in Action.

DataModel holds my ef entities (class definitions).  DataProvider holds my DbContext.  UserInterface is the startup web application.

I have the following in DataProvider > P1DbContext.cs :

```
namespace DataProvider
{
    public class P1DbContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<ToDoItem> ToDoItems { get; set; }

        public P1DbContext(DbContextOptions<P1DbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    }
}
```

And the following in DataProvider > ContextFactoryForMigrations.cs (this was suggested by Jon P Smith for migrations with multiple projects in one solution) :

```
class ContextFactoryForMigrations : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<P1DbContext>
{

    private const string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;";

    public P1DbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<P1DbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString,
            b => b.MigrationsAssembly("DataProvider"));

        return new P1DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }

}
```

And then I have this in UserInterface > Startup.cs :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string connection = "Server = localhost; Database = master; Trusted_Connection = True;";
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDbContext<P1DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection,
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("DataProvider")));
        }
```

Proper references are made and all projects compile.

When I go to Package Manager Console, I run the following, with DataProvider as the default project in PM Console and UserInterface as startup project in the solution :

```
Add-Migration InitializeDb -Project DataProvider -StartupProject UserInterface
```

I get this response :

```
Could not load assembly ''. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project ''.
```

It doesn't even appear to know what assembly to look for or what the startup project is.  I'm sure I'm missing something stupid here, but thought I would ask before I beat my head against the wall too much longer.

Here is a link to a repo with the current state of the project : https://github.com/philipwalter/CodeFirstEFTest

If someone can help me get over this initial Code First hump, I can handle the rest.

Comment: What path are you running your commands from? And what's your project layout on disk?

Comment: Layout on disk is c:\users\user\source\repos\master\, then master solution file under that and three folders for DataProvider, UserInterface, and DataModel.  I'm running the commands from Visual Studio using the Package Manager Console, so I assume that runs from the \repos\master\ folder?  I'm quite confused by the fact the message doesn't appear to even be looking for a named assembly or startup project.

Comment: You can run `Get-Location` to confirm it's running from where you think it is

Comment: It is running in the master solution directory.  I edited the original question to include a link to a github repo with the project.  This is a clone of everything under the master solution directory.  Perhaps that will help someone troubleshoot.  I'm sure I have something weird going on.  As a newb to code first development, I'm stumbling around in the dark a bit.

Comment: I just cloned your solution, ran `Add-Migration InitializeDb -Project DataProvider -StartupProject UserInterface` and it generated the migration. I wonder if there's something off with your VS install. Can you try from a normal powershell prompt?

Comment: Or maybe try `dotnet ef migrations add` instead

Comment: Hmmm.  I tried it from a PowerShell window, running in my master solution directory, but of course it doesn't recognize the Add-Migration term as a cmdlet etc.  Do I need to run a certain instance of powershell or install some other tools?

Comment: Here is what I got from `dotnet ef migrations add` -- `dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"` ... I must be missing something in my VS setup?

Comment: I think you might be missing the ef core tools

Comment: I have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools added to the UserInterface Project through NuGet.  What else should I be doing?

Comment: Try adding Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design to DataProvider or use `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`

Comment: Sorry to keep going around and around in the comments, but when I run `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef` I get `dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-tool"`  I'm clearly missing something in a config file or in my VS install.  Frustrating.

Comment: What version of the dotnet sdk do you have installed? `dotnet --list-sdks`

Comment: okay global tools are new in 2.1, so might as well try to add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` to the DataProvider project

Comment: So, here's what I get from `dotnet --list-sdks` : `dotnet : Unknown option: --list-sdks` and then a bunch of other info, including `.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.2)`.  I also added Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (3.1.4) to the DataProvider project but still get the same error from Add-Migration.  Perhaps I need to update the .NET CLI Tools somehow?  All 3 projects are .NET Core 2.0

Comment: Are you trying to use ef core 3 tools with a netcore 2 app? EF core 3 may be looking for a CreateHostBuilder method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was correctly diagnosed by Jeremy Lakeman in the comments above.  Using NuGet, I brought EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.x into a .NET Core 2.x project.  I removed those references and added EF versions to match my .NET Core version, and the Add-Migration command worked successfully.  Thanks to Jeremy and ESG for helping me out!